# WSO2 API Manager(wso2am-4.1.0) - How to Point an Already Existing JDBC Userstore?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm currently using wso2am-4.1.0 and I'm trying to point an already existing JDBC userstore to be used as secondary. It was pointed to a previous version(2.1.0) and the relevant script has been used to create the userstore.
When I point the same userstore using the latest version, the following exception pops up when listing the users.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'UM_USER_ID' in 'field list'
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
```

Is it possible to add the relevant column to the existing userstore or is there a workaround to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be due to the latest improvements done to the schema. I think there are two ways you can do this.

1. Change the queries from the config section so that core does not use the newly defined queries.
2. Migrate the existing userstore to the new userstore schema.

The 2nd option is the preferred approach. Check this sample [doc](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/5.11.0/setup/migrating-userstore-managers/). There can be another doc for APIM.